# How to programmatically disable or avoid closing gesture on webpage that is running inside Facebook webview on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, webview, frontend

I have webpage that majority of traffic coming through Facebook webview. On this page I have Swiper component edge to edge. Unfortunately, users are not able to swipe left because webview has the same gesture that closes webview. Swiping right works fine but swiping left closes view. It works as usual on regular, non-facebook-webview browsers e.g mobile Safari.
I tried to use `event.preventDefault()` in `onTouchStart` and `onTouchMove` handlers, CSS `touch-actions: none` but none of those worked. Also, none of Swiper properties - `edgeSwipeDetection='prevent'`, `touchStartForcePreventDefault={true}` helped.

I want to disable gesture only when user is interacting with Swiper, basically doing swipe left gesture on slides.

Comment: Just curious did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, wrapping around the swiper components. I'm using react-slick slider and I found this in slick-slider issues: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1240#issuecomment-513235261

```
let firstClientX, clientX;

const preventTouch = (e) => {
  const minValue = 5; // threshold

  clientX = e.touches[0].clientX - firstClientX;

  // Vertical scrolling does not work when you start swiping horizontally.
  if (Math.abs(clientX) > minValue) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    return false;
  }
};

const touchStart = (e) => {
  firstClientX = e.touches[0].clientX;
};

/**
 * Prevents closing gestures (e.g. swipe close on Facebook in app browser).
 */
export const PreventCloseGesture = ({ children }) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (containerRef.current === null) {
      return;
    }
    containerRef.current.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
    containerRef.current.addEventListener('touchmove', preventTouch, { passive: false });

    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) {
        containerRef.current.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
        containerRef.current.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventTouch, { passive: false });
      }
    };
  }, [containerRef]);

  return <div ref={containerRef}>{children}</div>;
};
```